# Lock the Windows XP machine over the network

Tags: windows, windows-xp, remote-access, remote-control

I'm a victim of funny prank: From time to time colleague uses "Lock computer" remotely over the network. How can I protect against it? How is he doing it? What information he must have? I guess he must know my password, machine name. Correct?

Comment: disable remote access to the computer.  If he is the admin of the domain then there is nothing you can do to prevent it.

Comment: If he is a domain admin and you are a user, nothing.  Chances are he is remotely running c:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation.  Since you can't exactly delete or rename the rundll32.exe, doing that wont work.